# wheel pollutes project folder with build & project.egg-info

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging, python-wheel

I use the `pip install c:\path\to\project` command to install my local package from a `pyproject.toml` configuration. It works fine and I can also uninstall the package with `pip uninstall project`. The only thing that makes me unhappy is the project folder being polluted with two extra folders: `build` & `project.egg-info`. The same happens when I try to build it  with `python -m pip wheel . -w .dist`. Is there any way to suppress or modify this behavior and keep the project folder clean?

```
project
|- pyproject.toml
|- project/
|  | - test.py
|- build/ <-- extra folder
|- project.egg-info/ <-- extra folder
```

Comment: What version of `pip`? There is a `pip install` flag `--no-clean Don't clean up build directories.` so I would have assumed that the default is to clean those directories afterwards... -- It might also be helpful to know what is the build back-end of the project (not sure it is relevant, but maybe).